# How to strip a string from the point a hyphen is found within the string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to strip a string of data that is may contain the hyphen symbol.

```
E.g. Basic logic:

string stringin = "test - 9894"; OR Data could be == "test";
if (string contains a hyphen "-"){
Strip stringin;
output would be "test" deleting from the hyphen.
}
Console.WriteLine(stringin);
```

The current C# code i'm trying to get to work is shown below:

```
    string Details = "hsh4a - 8989";
    var regexItem = new Regex("^[^-]*-?[^-]*$");
    string stringin;
    stringin = Details.ToString();

    if (regexItem.IsMatch(stringin)) {
    stringin = stringin.Substring(0, stringin.IndexOf("-") - 1); //Strip from the ending chars and - once - is hit.
    }
    Details = stringin;
    Console.WriteLine(Details);
```

But pulls in an Error when the string does not contain any hyphen's.

Comment: You dont need to do details.tostring .. its already a string.   If you're going to do "stringin = stringin.Substring(0, stringin.IndexOf("-") - 1);" why bother with regex, just check "-" exists.

Comment: I'm currently using toString() because this is a cut-down code example, within my full code its pulling data from an XML API using objects/different data sets in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is asking for "zero or one repetition of -", which means that it matches even if your input does NOT contain a hyphen. Thereafter you do this

```
stringin.Substring(0, stringin.IndexOf("-") - 1)
```

Which gives an index out of range exception (There is no hyphen to find).

Make a simple change to your regex and it works with or without - ask for "one or more hyphens":

```
var regexItem = new Regex("^[^-]*-+[^-]*$");
    here -------------------------^
```

Comment: Interesting downvote here, id be interested to know what someone thinks is wrong considering I [tried out this solution before posting it](http://rextester.com/SBNLHD79077)

Comment: @Mattlinux1 - I know :)

Answer (score 3):

How about just doing this?

```
stringin.Split('-')[0].Trim();
```

You could even specify the maximum number of substrings using overloaded `Split` constructor.

```
stringin.Split('-', 1)[0].Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want the (sub)string starting from the dash (`'-'`) if original one contains `'-'` or the original string if doesn't have dash.
If it's your case:

```
  String Details = "hsh4a - 8989";
  Details = Details.Substring(Details.IndexOf('-') + 1);
```

Comment: That will still give the wrong answer when no hyphen exists, no?

Comment: @Jamiec: if `Details` doesn't contain `'-'` then `Details.IndexOf('-')` returns `-1` and `Substring(0)` returns the entire `Details` string

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regex for this case if I were you, it makes the solution much more complex than it can be.
For string I am sure will have no more than a couple of dashes I would use this code, because it is one liner and very simple:

```
string str= entryString.Split(new [] {'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

If you know that a string might contain high amount of dashes, it is not recommended to use this approach - it will create high amount of different strings, although you are looking just for the first one. So, the solution would look like something like this code:

```
int firstDashIndex = entryString.IndexOf("-");
string str = firstDashIndex > -1? entryString.Substring(0, firstDashIndex) : entryString;
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a regex for this. A simple IndexOf function will give you the index of the hyphen, then you can clean it up from there.

This is also a great place to start writing unit tests as well. They are very good for stuff like this.

Here's what the code could look like :

```
string inputString = "ho-something";
string outPutString = inputString;

            var hyphenIndex = inputString.IndexOf('-');
            if (hyphenIndex > -1)
            {
                outPutString = inputString.Substring(0, hyphenIndex);
            }

            return outPutString;
```